# Spring Mongodb query DbRef (one to many relation)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a one to many relationship using Mongodb entities. I would like to find objects from the many part using some criteria. Is it possible using spring data mangodb?

e.g. In the below data model would like to find questions and it's attached answers which is created after certain time. like if question has 50 answer but only 2 is created after Aug 23,2015 I would like to fetch only these 2 answers for this question. How to achieve this using Spring data mongodb?

```
@Document(collection="question")
@TypeAlias("question")
public class Question implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Question() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @DBRef(lazy=true)
    private List<Answer> answers;

    //Audit fields create and lastupdate
}

@Document(collection="answer")
@TypeAlias("answer")
public class Answer extends CommonDomainAttributes implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4195056255932348897L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Answer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @TextIndexed
    private String answer;

    //Audit fields create and lastupdate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query it like this. Assuming you have a field named createdts in answer document.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("answers.createdts").gte(new DateTime("2015-08-23")));
```

Comment: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Invalid path reference address.city! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!

Comment: @Debopam I am not sure, why address.city comes into picture when we are running the above query. Is the mongoDB document posted in question is right?